# How to turn off/disable Skrill/Moneybookers in Magento

Tags: payment-gateway

now I don't want Skrill/Moneybookers, this payment method in Magento.
but I can't find where to turn it off or disable.

the website still show this payment link in payment page.
some customer still click and turn to their page for payment.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Comment: This is something you have done rather than a default Magento behaviour. Have you checked in the system config what you have enabled at the store view scope? Cleared cache, all those normal things?

Answer (score 2):

Woolfie is correct in his comment. You must have set this up before.

You need to go to System -> Configuration -> MoneyBookers (on the left hand side 3/4 of the way down). Once there, you should see several expandable blocks like in this screenshot:

[image: Moneybookers]

You need to go through all of these blocks (since I don't know which ones were touched) and make sure all are set to "No" for the option "Enabled". I would remove any usernames/passwords as well if they are set.

Once that is complete, I would refresh you cache and reload your checkout. If you see them still, you could have missed an option or it could be hardcoded in your theme (which would be a horrible practice).